# How to highlight selected table cells in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selection

I need , for instance, to get the hidden input values in the table cells when the user selects certain cells in a table row by dragging the mouse from the first cell to another one. How do I do this in AngularJS?

See picture for a better understanding: http://screencast.com/t/m3hcN11leTh

Comment: Well, you need to post your code, what you've tried, and where you're stuck. Creating a plunker would be useful (or jsfiddle/jsbin/etc).

Comment: To address your issue, you'd probably need to create a mousedown and mouseup listener on each cell, and then you can grab all cells between the first mousedown and the mouseup using angular element.

Answer (score 2):

If you are still looking for an answer, I developed a angular directive for multi-cell-selection in a table. You can find it on

In your script;

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.ids = [];
  $scope.rowTable = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  $scope.colTable = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23];
});
app.directive('multiCellSelect', function($window, $document) {

  return {
    scope: {
      multiCellIds: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope, $element) {
      var clearFlag = false;
      var startCell = null;
      var dragging = false;
      var finalCell = null;

      function mouseDown(el) {
        dragging = true;
        setStartCell(el);
        setRangeArea(startCell, el)
      }

      function mouseUp(el) {
        dragging = false;
        finalCell = el;
        setSelectedCells(startCell, finalCell);
        if (clearFlag) {
          clearCells(startCell, finalCell);
          clearFlag = false;
        }
        startCell = null;
      }



      function mouseLeave(el) {
        if (dragging) {
          if (el.hasClass('hover-area')) {
            cellsBetween(startCell, el).each(function() {
              var el = angular.element(this);
              el.toggleClass('hover-area').addClass('ui-state-default')
            });
            if (startCell == el) {
              el.toggleClass('hover-area').addClass('ui-state-default')
            }
          }
        } else {
          return;
        }
      }

      function mouseEnter(el) {
        if (!dragging) {
          return;
        } else {
          setRangeArea(startCell, el);
        }
      }

      function setStartCell(el) {
        startCell = el;
      }



      function setRangeArea(start, el) {
        if (dragging) {
          if (el.hasClass('ui-state-default')) {
            cellsBetween(startCell, el).each(function() {
              var el = angular.element(this);
              el.addClass('hover-area')
            });
          } else if (el.hasClass('hover-area') || el.hasClass('ui-state-default')) {
            cellsBetween(startCell, el).each(function() {
              var el = angular.element(this);
              el.toggleClass('hover-area').addClass('ui-state-default');
            });
          }

          if (!start.hasClass('eng-selected-item')) {
            cellsBetween(startCell, el).each(function() {
              var el = angular.element(this);
              if (el.hasClass('eng-selected-item')) {
                clearFlag = true;
              }
            });
          }

        }
      }

      function setSelectedCells(start, end) {
        if (start && end) {
          cellsBetween(start, end).each(function() {
            var el = angular.element(this);
            if (el.hasClass('eng-selected-item') && el.hasClass('hover-area')) {
              el.removeClass('eng-selected-item');
              el.removeClass('hover-area')
              var id = el.attr('id');
              var index = $scope.multiCellIds.indexOf(id);
              if ($scope.multiCellIds.indexOf(el.attr('id')) > -1) {
                $scope.multiCellIds.splice(index, 1);
              }
            } else if (el.hasClass('hover-area') && !el.hasClass('eng-selected-item')) {
              el.addClass('eng-selected-item');
              el.removeClass('hover-area')

              if ($scope.multiCellIds.indexOf(el.attr('id')) == -1) {
                $scope.multiCellIds.push(el.attr('id'));
              }
            }
          });
        }
      }

      function clearCells(start, end) {
        cellsBetween(start, end).each(function() {
          var el = angular.element(this);
          el.removeClass('eng-selected-item');
          el.removeClass('hover-area');
          var id = el.attr('id');
          var index = $scope.multiCellIds.indexOf(id);
          if ($scope.multiCellIds.indexOf(el.attr('id')) > -1) {
            $scope.multiCellIds.splice(index, 1);
          }
        });


      }

      function cellsBetween(start, end) {
        var coordsStart = getCoords(start);
        var coordsEnd = getCoords(end);
        var topLeft = {
          column: $window.Math.min(coordsStart.column, coordsEnd.column),
          row: $window.Math.min(coordsStart.row, coordsEnd.row),
        };
        var bottomRight = {
          column: $window.Math.max(coordsStart.column, coordsEnd.column),
          row: $window.Math.max(coordsStart.row, coordsEnd.row),
        };
        return $element.find('td').filter(function() {
          var el = angular.element(this);
          var coords = getCoords(el);
          return coords.column >= topLeft.column && coords.column <= bottomRight.column && coords.row >= topLeft.row && coords.row <= bottomRight.row;
        });

      }



      function getCoords(cell) {
        var row = cell.parents('row');
        return {
          column: cell[0].cellIndex,
          row: cell.parent()[0].rowIndex
        };

      }

      function wrap(fn) {
        return function() {
          var el = angular.element(this);
          $scope.$apply(function() {
            fn(el);
          });
        }
      }

      $element.delegate('td', 'mousedown', wrap(mouseDown));
      $element.delegate('td', 'mouseenter', wrap(mouseEnter));
      $element.delegate('td', 'mouseleave', wrap(mouseLeave));
      $element.delegate('td', 'mouseup', wrap(mouseUp));

    }
  }
});
```

In your html;

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

      <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <h1>
        <i>Multi Cell Selection by Zerocool27</i>
        </h1>
        <table ng-table="idTable" class="table table-striped" multi-cell-select multi-cell-ids="ids">
          <tr>
            <th colspan="1">Days</th>
            <th colspan="2" ng-repeat="col in colTable">{{col}}
          </tr>
          <tr ng-repeat="row in rowTable">
            <th>{{row}}</th>
            <td colspan="2" style="effect" class="ui-state-default" id="{{row}}-0"></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="effect" class="ui-state-default" id="{{row}}-1"></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="effect" class="ui-state-default" id="{{row}}-2"></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="effect" class="ui-state-default" id="{{row}}-3"></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="effect" class="ui-state-default" id="{{row}}-4"></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="effect" class="ui-state-default" id="{{row}}-5"></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="effect" class="ui-state-default" id="{{row}}-6"></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="effect" class="ui-state-default" id="{{row}}-7"></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="effect" class="ui-state-default" id="{{row}}-8"></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="effect" class="ui-state-default" id="{{row}}-9"></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="effect" class="ui-state-default" id="{{row}}-10"></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="effect" class="ui-state-default" id="{{row}}-11"></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="effect" class="ui-state-default" id="{{row}}-12"></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="effect" class="ui-state-default" id="{{row}}-13"></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="effect" class="ui-state-default" id="{{row}}-14"></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="effect" class="ui-state-default" id="{{row}}-15"></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="effect" class="ui-state-default" id="{{row}}-16"></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="effect" class="ui-state-default" id="{{row}}-17"></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="effect" class="ui-state-default" id="{{row}}-18"></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="effect" class="ui-state-default" id="{{row}}-19"></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="effect" class="ui-state-default" id="{{row}}-20"></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="effect" class="ui-state-default" id="{{row}}-21"></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="effect" class="ui-state-default" id="{{row}}-22"></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="effect" class="ui-state-default" id="{{row}}-23"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <div style="margin-top:20px;">
          <i>Selected Cells : </i>
          <span ng-repeat="id in ids">
          <i>{{id}}</i>
        </span>
        </div>


      </div>
    </body>
```

Your CSS;

```
td {
  border: 0px solid black;
}

td:hover {
  background: #8deaed;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#8deaed), to(#9fedf0));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#8deaed, #9fedf0);
  background: linear-gradient(#8deaed, #9fedf0);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #b9f2f5;
}

td,
th {
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #858584;
}

[multi-cell-select] {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -user-select: none;
}

[multi-cell-select] .eng-selected-item {
  background: #007AFF;
  color: white;
  border-bottom-color: #007AFF;
  border: #007AFF;
}

[multi-cell-select] .hover-area {
  background: #8deaed;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#8deaed), to(#9fedf0));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#8deaed, #9fedf0);
  background: linear-gradient(#8deaed, #9fedf0);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #b9f2f5;
}

.ui-state-default {
  border: 0px solid rgba(211, 211, 211, 0.54);
  background: #C0C0C0;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #63ad0d;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #63ad0d;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  background: #eee;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#eee, #e2e2e2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #aaa;
  color: #5A5757;
  font: bold 10px Arial, Helvetica, Clean, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I've created fiddle example for you.

https://jsfiddle.net/Zerocool27/dg98mc9u/16/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12778965)

Comment: @Laurel The link isn't a reference containing information, it's a link to a tool. Your autocomment makes no sense for such a link.

Comment: @MarkAmery It contains code, some of which should answer the question (theoretically). The important parts can be copied in, unless it's too much (and we should see if the question is too broad).

Comment: @Laurel Disagree that inclusion of such code is necessary. Suggestions to use a language's built-in functions needn't be accompanied by the implementation of the function, so why should suggestions of libraries need to be accompanied by any of the code that implements the library?

Comment: @MarkAmery We're not going to lose the implementation of built in functions if their GitHub link is broken/changed. I speak from [experience,](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321494) link only answers to libraries are bad in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by installing `ngx-cell-selectable`.
This is a stackblitz example about it.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-csqbzv